# Usar dependencia em 2 modulos diferentes

Tags: angular

Como eu faço para ter em modules diferentes, o mesmo componente no declarations?

Ex:

estado.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [ AdicionarEstado, ... ]
  ...
})
```

cidade.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [ AdicionarEstado, ... ]
  ...
})
```

Estou precisando disso pois vou ter um select que, o seu primeiro item será um botão fixo que irá abrir um modal para cadastrar um estado, alem de trazer os cadastrados. Isso será feito no cadastro de cidade... (quando necessário).

**EDIT**

Com import do estado na cidade

cidade.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ EstadoModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ]
  ...
})
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você pode colocar o AdicionarEstado no declarations e no exports do EstadoModule, e depois adicionar o EstadoModule no CidadeModule, assim o AdicionarEstado, como foi exportado pelo EstadoModule poderá ser usado no CidadeModule que está importando tudo que está declarado no EstadoModule. Já tentou fazer isso? Acredito que isso irá resolver seu problema.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, porem quando eu abro a view da cidade, é carregado o estado...

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo para vc ver

Comment: Cara, o Angular não permite vc declar 1 componente em dois módulos diferentes... o que vc pode fazer é encapsular o seu componente em outro módulo, mas não tenho ctz se entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Eu coloquei isso no edit, eu tentei fazer com o import do modulo, mas quando carrego uma view da cidade no caso, abre uma view do estado...

Comment: A ideia é poder cadastrar um estado dentro da view cidade, usando um modal, eu descrevi isso tambem no post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Consegui fazer com shared module**

cidade.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ]
  ...
})
```

estado.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule, ...],
  declarations: [ ... ]
  ...
})
```

shared.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        AdicionarEstadoComponent
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    bootstrap: [
    ],
    exports: [
        AdicionarEstadoComponent
    ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```